# Abort further program execution

Tags: c#, error-handling

I have a several nested methods in my program. If a deeply nested method errors out in my try block how do i stop further execution and print the error to the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether I'm understanding your question correctly...

But if you don't want to handle it in the deeper-down code, then don't catch it (or catch it and re-throw it again).

Exceptions travel up the call stack until something catches them.

Answer (score 0):

You can rethrow the exception within your `catch` block using `throw;`.  If you let this bubble to the top, your app can handle it and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is wrap the Exception in a custom exception and instruct your different try catchs to rethrow it, until it reaches a speciffic try catch block that you want to use to handle it.